# An expression for someone who causes "pain" and for those who receive this "pain"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, expressions

- What do you call a person who gives *only pain* to his dear ones (whom he cares about the most)?
- What do you call a person who gets *only agony* from the person he cares most?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the nature of the relationship, and the kinds of actions that caused such pain?

Comment: @Mari-Lou why'd you edit the dupe?

Comment: @curiousdannii I didn't see it! I only saw your comment later :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah, no worries then. :)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your previous one, so it is likely to be closed. Instead of creating a duplicate question, you should edit your own previous question to include the improvements you've made here.

Answer (score 2):

A person who causes pain can be called an ***abuser***, regardless if the people being physically harmed or emotionally hurt are close family members or complete strangers

> *abuser*: someone who regularly or habitually abuses someone or something, in particular.

The person who receives such abuse is often called a ***victim***.

> *victim*: an unfortunate person who suffers from some adverse circumstance